# как получить значение не из тега form

Tags: php

Мне нужно получить значение из тега

и внести его в переменную, как это сделать с помощью форм и get запросов я знаю, а как получить из других тегов значения и внести их в переменную?

Comment: из каких других тегов?

Comment: взять данные через js и отправить на сервер ajaxom или другим способом формирования запроса

Answer (score 1):

Из тега form тоже не так-то просто (только если это не параметр GET-запроса, указанного в атрибуте `action`)

Без использования Javascript вы моете отправить только данные из элементов формы ну или через ссылки (но там ничего не получится менять). Соответсвенно если вам нужно отправить данные, которые каки-то образом оказались в других тегах, придется написать скрипт, который достанет данные из нужных тегов и затем

- или добавит в параметры формы
- или сфформирует AJAX запрос